# How to use buttons inside a cell of a PySimpleGUI Table element?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Environment: Python 3.8, PySimpleGUI 4.47.0.

How to built a Table element with a cell containing a button or an image?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to embed other element into `sg.Table` or `sg.Tree`.

Two ways for it

1. Create a table by other elements, like array of `sg.Button`, `sg.Text`, ... (Refer https://github.com/jason990420/PySimpleGUI-Solution/issues/31)
2. Using icon column `'#0'` to show an image as an icon.

Here's the demo code to show how icon column work, basically, `sg.Tree` can do the same thing and much easy for it.

```py
from io import BytesIO
import base64

from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def size(base64_image):
    """
    Return size of image
    """
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_image)))
    width, height = im.size
    return f'{width} x {height}'

# Get name and image of all internal EMOJI base64 images
emoji = {
    key:value for key, value in sg.__dict__.items()
        if key.startswith("EMOJI_") and type(value)==bytes
}
keys = sorted(list(emoji.keys()))               # key list of images
dims = [[size(emoji[key])] for key in keys]     # size list of images

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Table(values=dims, headings=['Image Size'], row_height=64, key='-TABLE-',
        auto_size_columns=False, col_widths=[12], num_rows=3)],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
table = window['-TABLE-'].Widget
table.configure(show='tree headings')           # Show headings and in tree mode

images = []
for i, key in enumerate(keys):                  # Set text and icon for each row
    image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=emoji[key])
    images.append(image)
    table.item(i+1, text=key, image=image)

column0_width = (max(map(len, keys)) + 2)*sg.Text.char_width_in_pixels(font) + 64
table.column('#0', width=column0_width)         # width of Icon Column
table.heading('#0', text='Image')               # heading of Icon Column

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[image]

Demo code using `sg.Tree`

```py
from io import BytesIO
import base64

from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def size(base64_image):
    """
    Return size of image
    """
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_image)))
    width, height = im.size
    return f'{width} x {height}'

# Get name and image of all internal EMOJI base64 images
emoji = {
    key:value for key, value in sg.__dict__.items()
        if key.startswith("EMOJI_") and type(value)==bytes
}
keys = sorted(list(emoji.keys()))               # key list of images
dims = [size(emoji[key]) for key in keys]       # size list of images

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

treedata = sg.TreeData()
for key, (text, value) in enumerate(zip(keys, dims)):
    treedata.insert("", key, text, [value], icon=emoji[text])
col0_width = max(map(len, keys))+5

layout = [
    [sg.Tree(data=treedata, headings=['Image Size'], col0_width=col0_width,
        key='-TABLE-', row_height=64, auto_size_columns=False, col_widths=[12],
        num_rows=3)],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
table = window['-TABLE-'].Widget
table.heading('#0', text='Image')               # heading of Icon Column

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```